# How to validate a percentage to two decimal places with a Regex?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

Is there a regex that would validate a percentage value to 2 decimal places?

I have a regex for two decimal places, but don't know how to stop values above 100.  e.g. 100.01 is validated with my regex.

Comment: FWIW - parse the image into a float/double in whatever language you're using, and validate `0 <= x <= 100`. A regex is not the right hammer for this nail IMHO.

Comment: When I said "image", I meant "percentage". Sorry.

Comment: I'm using a datannotation regular expression to apply validation in an mvc app.

Comment: Littlechris, I'm not sure if you've noticed the new comments under DVK's answer.  But it should work for you if you remove the beginning and trailing slashes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Perl:

```
/(^100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,2})?)$/
```

or you can just add an extra if comparing 100 exactly :)

Comment: Nicely done.  It works with my test cases... http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=6807190b-cc82-4dd4-8864-05ce8c0c3b4f

Comment: Looks like it works on the link provided, but can get it to work in my app.  ASP.Net MVC vlaidation using data annotation:

[RegularExpression(@"/(^100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,2})?)$/")]

Comment: Yo can refactor this for better efficiency. The two parts before and after the | share an initial prefix and postfix, and it includes ^ and $. By making common parts common, you reduce the amount of backtracking needed when a part fails to match.

Comment: @littlechris - I'm not really familiar with ASP, sorry. Your initial question's tag was not .net specific. As stated, this was Perl - I'm unsure of the portability to .net

Comment: thnkas DVK.  my mistake I thought regex where pretty standard.  Cheers! +1

Comment: @littlechris - Try removing the forward slash at the beginning and end.  It should work just fine in .NET (that's what Regex Hero is using).

Comment: Duh... slashes are Perl RegEx operator. The pattern is inside the slashes. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This allows all percentages except zero.

```
^[1-9]{1}[0-9]?(?:\.\d{1,2})?$|^0\.\d{1,2}?$|100
```

Comment: You should add ^100$ instead of the 100 at the end of your expression, otherwise anything containing 100 is considered valid e.g. 100s.23

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
\d{1,2}\.\d{2}
```

That gives you a one digit or two digit number followed by exactly two decimal places.  If you want to allow tenths as well (ala 10.1) then try this:

```
\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}
```

Comment: That solution misses the value '100' or '100.00'.

Comment: Durr, I kept reading that the OP did NOT want 100.00.  Oh well, perhaps another time...

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?:100(?:\.0(?:0)?)?|\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$/
```

Works with:

- 100
- 100.0
- 100.00
- 99.99
- 0.01
- 5

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (accepts anything between 0 and 100 including 0.00 & 100.00:

```
^(100\.00|100\.0|100)|([0-9]{1,2}){0,1}(\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^([0-9]{0,2})(.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}$|^100$
```

use this regex for validate the percentage in the angular project or javascript project